# AzureStorageFile.Uri not returning the correct Uri with special character filenames resulting in 404 responses

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

I am writing a program to download all the data and metadata from a a given AzureStorage Account.
Im nearly done with the File section of the account but after testing my outputs, I've come accross something strange.

When I was checking the filename from files with special characters inside them such as `& é #`, the Uri given back by the AzureStorageFile.Uri method was not the same as the one in the AzureStorage Explorer.

An exemple would be a file named : `& é #New Rich Text Document.rtf`

The desired Uri output of the method would be the one AzureStorage Explorer is giving me when I right-click on the file and click on properties : `http://accountname.file.core.windows.net/share/%26%20%C3%A9%20%23New%20Rich%20Text%20Document.rtf`

But what I'm getting after running my code is the following : `https://accountname.file.core.windows.net/share/& é %23New Rich Text Document.rtf`

I'm guessing some special characters are not translated rightly during the conversion and I did not find similar problems on the topic.

EDIT : Fred Han did give a solution but a problem remains, when I get the `CloudFile` using `GetFileReference`, it has still the Uri property with special character.
When doing `File.FetchAttributes`, the request sent to the server is using the wrongly encoded `File.Uri` and I cannot change the value of the property

If I try to get the filename using its encoded representation, the `CloudFile.Uri` will be encoded again when doing server requests which will also results in 404

My goal here is to download the `CloudFile`, not just get the URI and I cannot do it since the request will be using a wrongly encoded URI

Update: I did download the file and all the other files containing special characters, but I did not use the `File.Uri` property to do it since it was badly encoded and I can't modify its value. I had to use the `GetFileReference`method to do so but directly using the entire file path and not only the filename as pointed out by the answers/comments below. I had then to correct by hand the filepath and then get the file reference and download it.

```
public CloudFile getFile()
    {
        CloudFileClient client = AzureWorker.Connector.FileClient;
        CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference(ShareName);
        CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

        string path = Uri.LocalPath.Substring(1, Uri.LocalPath.Length - 1);
        int index = path.IndexOf('/');
        path = path.Substring(index + 1, path.Length - index - 1).Replace("%25", "%");           
        index = path.LastIndexOf('/');
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(path);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            sb.Remove(index + 1, path.Length - index - 1);
            sb.Append(FileName);
            return root.GetFileReference(sb.ToString());
        }
        return root.GetFileReference(FileName);
    }
```

`Uri` is the Uri property of the CloudFile inside my class
`FileName` Is the Name property of the Cloudfile inside my class
I thought just stocking the Uri inside my class was sufficient so this function is designed to get the proper file with the Uri and some correction (working for folder with special characters in the name)

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry, I will not share my code as it is developped for a buisness, all the informations you need is in the question.

If you need precisions, the CloudFile object doest exist, I do get the correct reference on it, it's just the Uri field that is not correct.

I think I will have to make a custom function to encode and decode each part of the uri by hand.

Comment: All I am looking for is the code for how you're constructing the URI. I'm really not interested in the rest of your code.

Comment: I'm not constructing any Uri, I'm using the Uri property of the class AzureStorage.CloudFile, see below : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.uri?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_File_CloudFile_Uri

Comment: The `%23` in the URL is correctly encoding the `#` character, and the rest of the URL is unchanged (correctly per spec). So the URL is correct. I can paste it into a browser and it is interpreted correctly. Are you seeing failures when using the CloudFile object associated with this URL?

Answer (score 0):

I’m using the following code sample to get the Uri of a file named `& é #New Rich Text Document.rtf` from a file share named `sinequa-data`, as you said, the file name in Uri is not URL encoded. But the file share name is still `sinequa-data`, which does not return as `share`. You should make sure if you pass correct file share name when you get share reference using `fileClient.GetShareReference("{file_share_name}")`.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connection_string}");

CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();


CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("sinequa-data");

if (share.Exists())
{

    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("& é %23New Rich Text Document.rtf");

    if (file.Exists())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image]

The properties of the file in Azure storage explorer

[image]

Besides, if possible, you can encode your file name before you upload the file to your file share.

**edit:**

Azure storage explorer help us encode the file name in file Uri, but the Azure storage SDK do not do it, if you'd like to make the Uri is same as the one that Azure storage explorer returns, you can try the following code:

```
//Uri.EscapeUriString(file.Uri.ToString())

file.Share.Uri + "/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(file.Name).Replace("&", "%26")
```

[image]

**update:**

Firstly, as Michael Roberson mentioned, my file name is `& é %23New Rich Text Document.rtf` that is not same as yours, so if you copy and run my code in your program, you get 404 error.

Besides, I rename the file to `& é #New Rich Text Document.rtf` and modified the code, the sample code works for me, you can refer to it.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connection_string}");

CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
List<CloudFileShare> fl = fileClient.ListShares().ToList();

CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("sinequa-data");

if (share.Exists())
{

    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("& é #New Rich Text Document.rtf");


    if (file.Exists())
    {
        //encode the file name
        Console.WriteLine(file.Share.Uri + "/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(file.Name).Replace("&", "%26").Replace("#","%23"));

        //download file 
        file.DownloadToFile(@"d:\des1.rtf",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to encode / decode by hand the Uri in order to have a correct Uri in case the filename contains special characters, I can't change the filename before the upload as it will be client side. I don't know why Microsoft encode / decode only part of the special characters

Comment: Hi @PaulB, I edited the reply, please refer to it. If the reply is helpful, you can mark it as accepted answer, which can help others quickly find this thread and solve the similar problem.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer, I was just gonna do the encode / decoding for the escaped character by hand before I checked your answer.
Marked it as the valid one.

Comment: Update: I'm getting 404 when I request the fil using the Uri provided by the method you linked.
The explanation is in the Uri in the explorer, there is no special characters (such as amperstand), only % followed by numbers (the encoded values)
I do get correctly every files except the ones with special characters inside it.
You can even see in your exemple the Uri given by the method `Uri.EscapeUriString()` is not exactly the same than in the one in the Explorer.
Im still looking for an answer, in the meantine I'm going to do an encoding/decoding method by hand

Comment: ``not exactly the same than in the one in the Explorer`` edited the reply, you can check it and try to use ``file.Share.Uri + "/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(file.Name).Replace("&", "%26")``.

Comment: I'm running into another problem, I can get the right Uri after modification but when I get the file using a GetFileReference, I will get the file correctly but I cannot modify the Uri as it is only gettable and not settable.
Your answer does correct my problem at first but if I cannot modify the Uri inside the CloudFile by hand, it will still get me 404 responses.

Comment: ``My goal here is to download the CloudFile, not just get the URI`` Why not directly call ``file.DownloadToFile("file_path",FileMode.OpenOrCreate)``?

Comment: If you use the method `DownloadToFile`, it will result in doing this request : `GET /sinequa-data/&%20%C3%A9%20%2523New%20Rich%20Text%20Document.rtf HTTP/1.1`
It uses the Uri inside the CloudFile to emit the request to the server which is wrongly encoded and thus result in a 404 response.
The path parameter inside the `DownloadToFile` method is just the path where to put the file after the download (I think or I'm maybe missing something)

Comment: This answer seems to be getting a reference to a file named `& é %23New Rich Text Document.rtf` while the question specified a file named `& é #New Rich Text Document.rtf`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRoberson-MSFT, it is my mistake, thanks for pointing out. I updated the reply.